# Play sound with max volume on default (speaker) device with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to play a warning sound using nodejs (with electron), that should always be played on the systems default device (speakers) at max volume, even though volume is turned low or headphones are connected.
So far I use 
[naudiodon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/naudiodon) to play the sound, which works using the device id, but if the volume is turned low, the sound plays low too.

Is there any other possibility to access the systems speakers and adjust the volume as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [loudness](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loudness)

```
import { getVolume, setVolume } from 'loudness';

const vol = await getVolume();
setVolume(100).then(() => {
  // Say your warning here...
  // Set volume back to the previous level
  setVolume(vol);
});
```

Comment: that would only help to set the volume if no external headphones are connected